# Show convergence of a series for $p\in (0,1), p\neq\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $p\in (0,1)$ and consider
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(4p(1-p))^n.
$$
For $p=\frac{1}{2}$ it is $(4p(1-p))^n=1$ and thus
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(4p(1-p))^n\geq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\infty
$$
and the series diverges.

If $p\in (0,1), p\neq\frac{1}{2}$ then $(4p(1-p))^n<1$.

It is said then in this case the series converges. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for all $n \geq 1$ we have $$0 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(4p(1-p))^n < (4p(1-p))^n$$

and  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (4p(1-p))^n$ converges, as $|4p(1-p)| = 4p(1-p) < 1$.

(By the way, I assume your sum should be from $n = 1$, not $n = 0$.)

Hence the partial sums $S_N = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(4p(1-p))^n$ are an increasing sequence bounded above and therefore have a limit.

Hence  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}(4p(1-p))^n$ converges.